# way to handle to write CUDA+MEX code in linux?

Tags: matlab, coding-style, cuda, mex

I try to write matlab mex code with Cuda integrated but it is just hard enough to compile and debug all around. Is there any better approach to code and test? I am on Matlab 2012b.

Currently I am writing code in sublime then compile it on matlab but I am also newbie at CUDA as well thus it is just hard to code it without seeing the result instantly.

Comment: It's [not necessary](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/executing-cuda-or-ptx-code-on-the-gpu.html) to use the mex mechanism anymore to run CUDA code from within matlab.   This non-mex technique should allow you to write independent (non-matlab) test cases to test your kernels functionality before stitching them into matlab.

Answer (score 2):

The comment by Robert Crovella is interesting.

I just wanted to mention the way I was used to compile mex file with CUDA instructions (and which works also on different versions of MATLAB).

1) Compile by `nvcc` and transform the source code in C++ code by the command

```
 system(sprintf('nvcc -I"%s/extern/include" -cuda "mex-fun.cu" -output-file "mexfun.cpp"', matlabroot));
```

2) Link it to Matlab by

```
mex -I/opt/cuda/include -L/opt/cuda/lib -lcudart mex-fun.cpp
```

This was originally suggested at the [MATLAB Newsreader page](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/261866).

Answer (score 1):

I have both a matlab entry point (i.e. a file with the function "mexFunction") and a C++ entry point (a file with "main"), and the rest of my actual CUDA code is independant of what entry point was used. 
This way, I can debug the code used for my MEX files using the standard set of CUDA tools (i.e. nvprof, cuda-memcheck, etc) without having to deal with the MEX file. Then once I'm sure I have no bugs or memory leaks, I just compile it to a MEX file. Alternately you can always just attach cuda-gdb to your MEX file, although your mileage may vary with this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but What does it mean to have different entry points for mex or CUDA or plain C code... Sorry about my ignorance .

Comment: lets say your code is in some file cu_kernels.cu, then you'd have 2 other files, i.e. main.cpp and mex_main.cpp which would contain your function main and mexFunction respectively. That way, you can invoke it from the command line or an IDE through your main.cpp, and you can compile it to a MEX file and call it from matlab via your mex_main.cpp file, and they both share the same code in cu_kernels.cu. Does that make sense?